# Which exact UIFont or font is used on the home screen for the icon titles?

Tags: iphone, fonts

I need the exact same font in my app, with the exact same size. Does anyone know?

Comment: sorry, didn't notice this function. accepted all good answers. thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be the font you're looking for, but I haven't found any documentation that confirms as such:

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [UIFont smallSystemFontSize] seemed slightly bigger when compared with the home screen labels under the app icons.  I tried [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize] - 1.0], and it seemed to be an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

The icon titles appear to use a UILabel with truncate in the middle, width of 74. The font is System bold, size 11